# Taking textarea value clicking on a submit that's not in the same form

Tags: php, html, forms, post

Is that possible? I have 2 divs. One of them with a cancel and a submit button (edit_cancel and edit_save), and another one with a div and a textarea (description and description_edit).
The div contais the user's description.
The text area is for writting the new description that I'm gonna import in the database, clicking in the submit button afterwards.

This is the code. But I dont know how to get the textarea value clicking the submit button.

```
<div id="user_profile">
    <img src="include/images/videos/profile-background.jpg" />
    <a id="changeBackground"><i class="fa fa-camera awesome"></i></a>

    <div class="profile">
        <img src="<?php DataBase::PrintImagenPerfil(); ?>" />
            <a id="changeProfile"><i class="fa fa-camera awesome"></i></i></a>
    </div>

    <div class="edit_profile">
        <div class="edit_buttons">
            <form action="perfil.php" method="POST">
                <input type="button" id="edit_cancel" name="edit_cancel" class="btn" value="Cancelar" />
                <input type="submit" id="edit_save" name="edit_save" class="btn" value="Guardar" />
            </form>
        </div>
        <a id="edit_profile_btn" class="btn">Editar perfil</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="user_info">
<div class="left">
    <h4 class="brandom-title"><?php DataBase::PrintNombreUsuario(); ?></h4>
    <p class="user_info brandom-title">Creado el <span><?php DataBase::PrintFechaCreacion(); ?></span></p>
    <p class="description"><?php DataBase::PrintDescripcion(); ?></p>
    <textarea id="description_edit" name="description_edit" cols="40" rows="6" aria-required="true"><?php DataBase::PrintDescripcion(); ?></textarea>
</div>

<div class="right">
    <h4 class="brandom-title"><i class="icon-group awesome"></i><?php DataBase::PrintSeguidores(); ?></h4>
    <div class="heart"><i class="fa fa-heart awesome"></i></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you not wrapping the both of divs with the form? In other words, why the textarea is outside from the form?

Comment: True... oh my good. I'm completely worn out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a hidden input in your form:

```
<form>
    ...
        <textarea id="hidden_textarea" name="hidden_textarea" hidden></textarea>
    ...
</form>
```

And then update this using javascript's `onchange` event in conjunction with the textarea `description_edit`

For instance:

```
document.getElementById("description_edit").onchange = function() {
    document.getElementById("hidden_textarea").value = document.getElementById("description_edit").value;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jofish999/8ab0jrg5/